# Sending Queries to a database from android

Tags: android, mysql, listview

I have a listview of sports on android. Is there a way of sending a MySQL queries with the selected option to a **remote** database with more info about the sport in the same table

Like.... SELECT football FROM table

Thanks in advance,
Zach

Comment: Do you want to access a local database in your app? if that is the case, Please refer to http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteOpenHelper.html

Comment: I want to access a remote database...

Answer (score 0):

The common database-type for android is sqlite.org

check out this [tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidSQLite/article.html) !!

it shows how to get the connection to the database and how to retrieve/write values there.

Comment: Can i copy the contents of the remote MySQL database to a local sqlite database when I load the app?

Comment: i bet you can. but copiing an entire db at every start of the app sounds pretty odd... the Android-API just offers the local SQLite-support, so i bet it is not meant to connect to a remote db. (rookie's opinion :-) )

Comment: A) no need to copy the entire db every time. Just do it at first startup, then check for changes on every connection after that. B) Its still impractical, see my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to give [This](http://capdroid.wordpress.com/2012/07/10/configuring-and-accessing-mysql-jdbc-driver-on-android-application/) a shot. They are using the jdbc bridge to connect to mysql.
Doesn't sound too sophisticated at a first glance, too... just seems to be plain old java.